# Error al poner `@Url.Action` como un string en una variable js

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvc, razor

Necesito poner este `@Url.Action` como un string en una variable js.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("MostrarLibro", "Usser", new { idLibro = originalList[z].IdLibro})">originalList[z].Nombre(originalList[z].AnioDeLanzamiento)</a>
```

tengo esto hecho, pero me esta marcando un error de sintaxis en el string donde esta el @Url.Action, probe quitando y agregando comillas ("") pero no hubo cambios.

```js
var originalList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.OriginalList));

var data = "";
              
        for (var z = desde; z <= hasta; z++) {

            data += "<div class='col-md-3 container-image text-center'>";

            data += "<img src='/" + originalList[z].UrlImagen + "' alt='" + originalList[z].Nombre + "'>";

            data += "<div class='title-book text-center'>";

            data += "<a href=@Url.Action('MostrarLibro', 'Usser', new { idLibro = originalList[z].IdLibro})>" + originalList[z].Nombre + "(" + originalList[z].AnioDeLanzamiento + ")</a>";

            data += "</div>"

            data += "<div class='price-book text-center'>" + "$"+ originalList[z].Precio + "</div>";

            data += "</div>";

        }

        $('#cont-libros').html(data);
```

Comment: No puedes poner comillas dobles dentro de comillas dobles, tu estas colocando en el html comillas dobles dentro de comillas dobles.

Comment: Gracias @Riven pero sigue sin tomar la parte de "@UrlAction" como string, pareciera que el  símbolo @ es el problema. aca muestro lo que acabo de corregir siguiendo tu consejo sobre las comillas. data += "<a href=@Url.Action"+"('MostrarLibro', 'Usser', new { idLibro = originalList[z].IdLibro})>" + originalList[z].Nombre + "(" + originalList[z].AnioDeLanzamiento + ")"+"</a>";

Comment: segun lo que pusiste en el anterior comentario siguen habiendo problemas, en tu caso ahora es que te falto abrir comillas `"` antes de  `@UrlAction`, de todas maneras veo que el problema es en ambas partes, tanto en el html como en el javascript, la verdad es que yo solo me referia al HTML cuando vi ese error, pero por lo que veo tienes un error parecido en tu javascript...

Comment: Tampoco sirve, abrí las comillas al principio de @UrlAction, evidentemente no me quiere reconocer el @ en un string. es mas si en js declaro esta variable por ejemplo var a = "@" o var a = @;  tira error.

Comment: de hecho no, el segundo caso por razones obvias dara error, pero el primero lo he probado y lo permite, tiene que ser que se te estan escapando valores o tienes alguna que otra comilla o comillas que te estan causando problemas, pero pues a mi parecer si tu ya solucionaste el error de las comillas entonces me gustaria que colocaras con que comando intentas ejecutar el script, puesto que al parecer `razor` se compila al igual que `angular`, si no lo ejecutas desde la terminal usando algun comando especial que tiene `razor` entonces ese es el inconveniente realmente.

Comment: me puedes pasar la sintaxis del primero que has probado? ese que dices que te lo permite por favor.

Comment: Es que lo que probe fue lo de aqui de los comentarios pero en javascipt enrealidad xd, es decir, yo probe fue esta linea `var a = "@"`.

Comment: yo también lo estoy probando en javascript, de hecho todo el código que publique esta hecho en javascript, no se cual es el error.

Comment: si le quito el simbolo @ al string , javascript no tira error de sintaxis. A continuacion muestro el string sin el simbolo de @:

Comment: data +="<a href=Url.Action('MostrarLibro', 'Usser', new { idLibro =" + originalList[z].IdLibro +"})>" + originalList[z].Nombre + "(" + originalList[z].AnioDeLanzamiento + ")</a>";